# Задать минимальный размер окна sfml

Tags: sfml, окно

как задать лимит на минимальный размер экрана sfml? Чтобы нельзя было допустим изменить размер экрана меньше (800, 800), то есть пользователь не сможет изменить экран до (600,600).

Answer (score 0):

Всё дело в "sf::Style::Close". Почитать можно [здесь](https://www.sfml-dev.org/documentation/1.6/namespacesf_1_1Style.php)!

```
sf::RenderWindow window(sf::VideoMode(800, 800), "ToTheBottom", sf::Style::Close);
```